# How best to generate a dynamically repeating series of values?

Tags: r

I would like to generate a vector with repeating values, but what to repeat and how often they repeat depends upon a value in a data frame along with the number of times to repeat that particular value.

Suppose I create the following data frame:

```
dfFoo <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3), numTimes = c(3, 2, 1))
```

How could I generically create the following vector:

```
1,1,1,2,2,3
```

I tried the following:

```
rep(dfFoo$id, each = dfFoo$numTimes)
```

which sadly only picks up the first element. I could use a for loop but that isn't very R-ish and apply seems like overkill. Any suggestions? TIA

Comment: Just `rep(dfFoo$id, dfFoo$numTimes)` or fully written: `rep(dfFoo$id, times = dfFoo$numTimes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rep(dfFoo$id, times = dfFoo$numTimes)
```

You just used the wrong rep argument